# Primefaces WAB - NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/FacesContextFactory

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, osgi

I have a `primefaces` jar packaged with WAB (under `WEB-INF\lib`)

Whenever I deploy the WAB, I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/context/FacesContextFactory
```

It seems that the primefaces classes cannot find any of the java faces classes in the glassfish runtime.

I've made sure that I only have ONE java faces in my classpath.

Can anyone give some suggestion?

My Manifest bundle classpath looks like this:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes,
 WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar,
 WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.2.1.jar,
 WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.3.jar,
 .
```

Comment: Add `jsf-api-xxx.jar` to your project

Comment: Oh that's the first thing I tried! Got `FacesContexFactory was not configured properly` error.
Apparently, glassfish already has its own java faces jar, and adding one makes it confused.